# What wrong with snat in nftables?

Tags: iptables, vpn, nat, ip6tables, nftables

I have two virtual machines (server, client) with wireguard vpn.
When i try ping any IPv6 resource from client packets doesn't return to client.

Tcpdump show me ICMP Reply packets in enp0s3 interface (server), not in wg0 (vpn interface on server).
But if disable nftables and start ip6tables, all works.
After this step i disable ip6tables and enable nftables... All continue works...

Software versions:

```
NixOS: 17.09.git.ebaff59 (Hummingbird)
WireGuard: 0.0.20170706
Nftables: 0.7
```

Build ISO images with next commands:

Server:

```
nix-build -A config.system.build.isoImage -I nixos-config=./wireguard_server_10.nix ./nixpkgs/nixos/default.nix
```

Client:

```
nix-build -A config.system.build.isoImage -I nixos-config=./wireguard_client_20.nix ./nixpkgs/nixos/default.nix
```

Here nix files:

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/d6d8b8b6acff715368844a643775c980

Create virtual machines with next commands:

Server:

```
virt-install \
--name NixOSVS10 \
--ram 1024 \
--vcpus 1 \
--cdrom /tmp/nixos_10.iso \
--os-type linux \
--nodisk \
--network bridge=br0 \
--graphics vnc,password="ABCDEF",port=5910,listen=2a01:4f8:xx:xx::13 \
--autostart \
--noautoconsole
```

Client:

```
virt-install \
--name NixOSVS20 \
--ram 1024 \
--vcpus 1 \
--cdrom /tmp/nixos_20.iso \
--os-type linux \
--nodisk \
--network bridge=br0 \
--graphics vnc,password="ABCDEF",port=5920,listen=2a01:4f8:xx:xx::13 \
--autostart \
--noautoconsole
```

Nftables rules:

Server:

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/17827298ad81970cc272b9e7f779923f

Client:

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/ad05f19759e02f92aac5d9c246f56cf6

Output for ip a, ip -6 route, route -6, wg, sysctl -a, dmesg, lsmod.

Server:

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/1a8c9f5aacf8957502299d707a38c5fc

Client:

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/b7dc077249ca513ca8f307a68c62d1ce

Tcpdump logs from client. Ping IPv6 address 2001:19f0:7400:87a2::64 (https://ipv6.net/)

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/03e716fba67c4119772012777847c569

Output from /proc/net/nf_conntrack:

With nftables:

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/601170680ff644c52a11e5352997879a

With ip6tables:

- https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/e043101f98e787c8cbf6d0605fd9de7e

Snat doesn't work correctly in nftables. But work after next steps:

```
[root@nixos:~]# systemctl stop nftables
[root@nixos:~]# ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j SNAT --to-source 2a01:4f8:xx:xx::10
```

Comment: am I just not seeing it, or did you ask a question about nftables without including your ruleset?

Comment: Ok, now edited...

Comment: So your nft snat is `ip6 saddr fc00::/64 oif enp0s3 nftrace set 1 counter snat 2a01:4f8:xx:xx::10` and your iptables is this `ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j SNAT --to-source 2a01:4f8:xx:xx::10`?  You have different rules.  The nft rule requires a certain source address range.  What happens if you change your nft rule to actually match the iptables rule?

Comment: Nothing changed. Doesn't work.

Comment: Current nftables rules - https://gist.github.com/MrSorcus/54684d8cd7a5e722a6f592b671432b0a

Comment: In that most recent set of rules in the comment the POSTROUTING chain doesn't have the `type nat hook postrouting priority 0;` line.  If you don't set a chain to be hooked to anything, I don't think it will actually do anything.

Comment: And what i should do? I used information from here - https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)

Comment: No ideas? What could be the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge of nftables is relatively week, I have just started playing around with it.

Comment: With git-version of nftables, libmnl & libnftnl doesn't work too...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved.
http://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=150027256708621&w=2

> You are probably lacking the reply NAT chain, which needs to be registered.
>
> https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)
>
> I'm updating right now the wiki to put this in bold.